# How to Stop postBack on pressing Tab button in rad grid numeric filter?

Tags: c#, telerik

I have set the Rad Numeric Filter's `autopostback` property equals to `true` and `currentfilter` function is equal to of the `current Numeric` column. Now when i put some text in numeric filter text box and press tab button then the page is postback automatically. How to stop this postback on pressing tab button.

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="Taskhrs" HeaderText="Task Hours" FilterControlWidth="50px"
      HtmlEncode="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="EqalTo" />
```

when put some value in filter text box and press enter it's working fine but when we press tab button then it also postback but i want to stop postback on pressing tab button .

Answer (score 2):

Write a jQuery and  find the `GridNumericColumn`. Now just find the press event of the `Tab` button and set the focus to the closest element in the Dom. (As i think the focus is not setting up properly.)

After your code of disabling the postback.

```
//Selects the closest element that matches your selector
$(this).closest('yourSelector');
```

Set the focus

```
$('#yourclosestid').focus();
```